# Proving that a convex subset of a Banach space can be totally bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I apologize for the question, but I'm really stuck. I've lost some of my notes and the class does not strictly follow a textbook, otherwise I'd be searching for the appropriate theorems.

Let **X** be a Banach space and **A** be a totally bounded subset of **X**. How can I prove that *conv*(**A**) is totally bounded as well?